# How to find out the URL of a file when uploaded with Filezilla

Tags: url, ftp, filezilla, fileserver

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I would like to know how to find out the URL of a file after it has been uploaded to a file server, so that I can view it in ex. safari.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible... FileZilla has no idea how FTP paths map to HTTP paths or if there even is an HTTP path to get to whatever you uploaded

Comment: Is there a way to find it out without Filezilla, or to establish a path if there isn't one?

Comment: Ask your server administrator or look in their documentation is the best answer we can give you.  There is no standardized mapping that any tool or other person could help you with.

Answer (score 1):

i think , this action is needed. but filezilla not supported.

but you can use this web app client.

[Ftp path To http path (view demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/pu7sp2rp/3/)

**html code**

```
<h2>Ftp path To http path</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="http_path">http base path</label></td>
    <td><input id="http_path" type="text"> (e.g., http://example.com)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="ftp_path">ftp path</label></td>
    <td><input id="ftp_path" type="text"> (e.g., ftp://username@domainOrIp/path)</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="output">output</label></td>
    <td><input id="output" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**css code**

```
#http_path,#ftp_path{
  width : 200px;
}
#output{
  width : 500px;
}
```

**js code**

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    //w3schools.com
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
} 
function getCookie(cname) {
    //w3schools.com
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
} 

$(function(){
    $('#http_path').val(getCookie('http_path'));
    $('#http_path,#ftp_path').change(function(e){
        setCookie('http_path',$('#http_path').val(),365);
        $('#output').val(
            $('#http_path').val() 
            + '/' +
            $('#ftp_path').val().split('/').slice(3).join('/')
       );
  });
  $('#output').click(function(){
    $(this).select();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other FTP client software does have this ability. The OSX client "Fetch", for example, asks you for the root http directory the first time you try to get a URL, and then remembers this. If you do this the first time in the highest level http directory, then it will also work for subdirectories.

Answer (score -1):

Right click the remote file and select "Copy URL to clipboard", then paste somewhere else. Of course this is only getting you the FTP URL of the file.